# Change Post Title For Specific Category

Tags: posts, categories, title

please I need help with this code

```
add_action( 'the_title', 'adddd', 10, 2 );
function adddd( $title, $post_id ) 
{
    if( has_category( 30, $post_id ) ) {
        $title = 'Prefix ' . $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Changing the post title of a specific category.

The code above is working fine displaying the prefix but am getting error when I  tried adding a word or two after the post title.

Please any fix for this?  Thanks.

Comment: please post the code which is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should use filter not action:

```
function adddd( $title, $post_id ) {
    if( in_category( 30 ) ) {
        $title = 'Prefix - ' . $title . ' - xxx';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'adddd', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks very much. My own code is working fine. What I wanted was to add additional word after the post title. Can you help me with the full code? Thanks

Comment: Just add this word after $title. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It returned an error. So I just edited mine adding   `. ' xxx'`  after the title

```
add_action( 'the_title', 'adddd', 10, 2 );
function adddd( $title, $post_id ) 
{
    if( has_category( 30, $post_id ) ) {
        $title = 'Prefix  ' . $title . '  xxx';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

It's working as it should now. Thanks very much for your help.